# Ubuntu 14.04 problem with network bandwidth limit

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I have a problem with my internet bandwidth on WiFi. Currently I have two computers: one with ubuntu 14.04 and second with Windows7.
On my Ubuntu machine when I try to download something I always have transfer about 400-500KB/s, but on my Windows7 machine I can download with transfer 2-3MB.
On Ubuntu machine I disabled Ipv6, but still nothing.

```
enter code hereeth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"UPC781972"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: CC:35:40:76:D4:52   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:5  Invalid misc:255   Missed beacon:0
```

I have read so far few tips about impoving network connection on 'AskUbuntu', but my WiFi works still in the same way. Does someone came on the same problem and solve it?

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 73
       serial: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-43-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 ip=192.168.0.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:61 memory:e3500000-e3501fff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. For about 2h i'm trying to figure out that's going on and i'm changed frequency of router 2.4GHz to 5Ghz and this solve the problem. I have many different 2.4GHz routers working in my neighborhood and this coul'd by the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Agg TX is disabled by default in iwlwifi, enabling it has helped quite a few people

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If the speed is back to normal, you can make the change persistant with the following

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

It also helps to have the router encryption set to WPA2-AES only with no TKIP, WEP, or WPA